# How to get blob Uri using azure Java Storage SDK V10

Tags: java, azure, rx-java, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I tried following [azure storage Samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/Samples.java) and am able to upload the blob. I am trying to get the Uri of the uploaded blob but I couldn't get the Uri.

In the previous SDK v7, I was able to do blobItem.getUri(), but couldn't find it in the new version. I tried the following, however the metadata doesn't have the Uri, its actually the properties. How do I get the Uri

```
    blobURL.upload(Flowable.just(ByteBuffer.wrap(image)), image.length, headers, mData, null, null)
    .flatMap(bulkBlockBlobUploadResponse -> {
        this.getContext().getLogger().info(bulkBlockBlobUploadResponse.headers().eTag());
        return Single.just(true);
    })
    .flatMap(response ->
        // Query the blob's properties and metadata.
        this.getBlockBlobURL().getProperties(null, null))
    .flatMap(blobGetPropertiesResponse -> { 
        this.getContext().getLogger().info(blobGetPropertiesResponse.headers().metadata().toString());
        return Single.just(true);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer a little late but on the **BlockBlobURL** object you have a **toURL()** method.
So to get the URI you just have to do :

```
BlockBlobURL my_blob = ... // your call to obtain the BlockBlobURL
URI blob_uri = blob.toURL().toURI();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the difference of the version of the sdk, there is a sample for reference.

```
static void getBlob(BlockBlobURL blobURL, File sourceFile) {
    try {
        // Get the blob using the low-level download method in BlockBlobURL type
        // com.microsoft.rest.v2.util.FlowableUtil is a static class that contains helpers to work with Flowable
        blobURL.download(new BlobRange(0, Long.MAX_VALUE), null, false)
        .flatMapCompletable(response -> {
            AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths
                .get(sourceFile.getPath()), StandardOpenOption.CREATE,  StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
                    return FlowableUtil.writeFile(response.body(), channel);
        }).doOnComplete(()-> System.out.println("The blob was downloaded to " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath()))
        // To call it synchronously add .blockingAwait()
        .subscribe();
    } catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

You can click this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java-v10) to check it in detail, hope it benefit.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, your sample shows how to download blob to local, whereas I was looking for the Uri of the uploaded blob. I had a look at the [blobUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._block_blob_u_r_l?view=azure-java-stable) the toURL() provides the blockBlob's url, and this helps me